# inserting a string value into viewmodel list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I posted a similar question two weeks ago, but was having issues getting it to debug successfully.  Thanks to @Stephen Muecke for helping me troubleshoot that.  I am reposting, since am not getting any traction on the second half of the problem, outlined below.

Working on a site function that shows a list of companies, based on a membertype, but I am running into an issue in how the list is being built in C#.  When I test the code, I get an unhandled exception error, and debugging indicates that the list is empty.

Here is the viewmodel:

```
public class MemberListViewModel
{
    public List<string> MemberList { get; set; }
    public string MemberType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public class MemberListController : Controller
{
public ActionResult MemberList()
{
    return PartialView(PrepareMemberListViewModel());
}

private MemberListViewModel PrepareMemberListViewModel()
{
    MemberListViewModel viewModel = new MemberListViewModel();

    string orgType = "Distributor"; //TODO: hardcoded for dev

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=db.site.net;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=SA;Password=PW"))
    {
        connection.Open();
if (orgType == "Manufacturer")
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Member FROM dbo.view WHERE [Member Type] = 'Manufacturer' and [Member Code] <> 'Associate - HBW'", connection))
                table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        else if (orgType == "HBW")
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Member FROM dbo.view WHERE [Member Type] = 'Manufacturer' and [Member Code] = 'Associate - HBW'", connection))
                table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        else
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Member FROM dbo.view WHERE [Member Type] = '" + orgType + "'", connection))
                table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
connection.Close();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string memberName = table.Rows[i]["Member"].ToString();
            viewModel.MemberList.Add(memberName);
        }

    return viewModel;
}
}
```

When I debug, everything runs smoothly until we get to

```
viewModel.MemberList.Add(memberName);
```

At that line, the local value for viewModel.Memberlist stubbornly stays at null.  I have confirmed that the table has values - in this case, 35 rows, with company names.

I know I am missing something simple, but am a noob, so not sure what it is.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've never instantiated your list.

Comment: Instantiate your MemberList

Comment: It's a good practice to instantiate list properties in a class's constructor so that you never access an null list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `Add` method on `NULL`, hence getting the typical null reference exception.

Make sure you initialize it to an empty collection before calling any method on it /accessing it.

```
var viewModel = new MemberListViewModel();
viewModel.MemberList= new List<string>();
```

Or using the object initializer syntax

```
var viewModel = new MemberListViewModel
                    {
                        MemberList= new List<string>()
                    };
```

IMHO, collection type properties should never be null, if no data, it should be an empty list. So another way to fix your problem is by updating your class definition to have a constructor which initialize this property to an empty list.

```
public class MemberListViewModel
{
    public List<string> MemberList { get; set; }
    public string MemberType { get; set; }

    public MemberListViewModel()
    {
       this.MemberList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple...  Thank you, @Shyju, and thanks for the explanation.  I agree with your reasoning on your third recommendation, so went with that, presto - page works.  Thanks again!